# LLVM front end register class error OpenCL -- GPU target

Tags: opencl, llvm, gpgpu, llvm-ir

I've recently been encountering this error when compiling OpenCL kernel files with my LLVM_IR pass:

```
aoc: ../../../TargetRegisterInfo.cpp:89: const llvm::TargetRegisterClass* llvm::TargetRegisterInfo::getMinimalPhysRegClass(unsigned int, llvm::EVT) const: Assertion `BestRC && "Couldn't find the register class"' failed.
```

I'm not sure what this means. What I've read from the documention doesn't make a lot of sense. Basically it means the backend doesn't know what type to place into the register?

Does anyone know what the error means?

It occurs in various kernels and doesn't seem to have a definitive pattern I can show as an example. I can post more details if needed, but really I'd just like to know what the error is telling me.

Thanks ahead of time for any help.

UPDATE:
It seems this command in LLVM is causing the issue:

```
AllocaInst* llvm::IRBuilder< preserveNames, T, Inserter >::CreateAlloca(Type * Ty, Value * ArraySize = 0,const Twine &  Name = "")
```

It creates this error when I do a nonspecific allocation in this manner. The reason I use this command is that sometimes in a kernel there will be a store value that is a Constant. Since LLVM often requires a Value I needed a way of converting it. So I do a an allocation with an immediate store and load. This was suggested by another SOF user. Does anyone know an alternate method of converting a Constant to a Value in LLVM?

Thanks all.

Ok it seems a conventional:

```
Value *new_val = dyn_cast<Value>(old_val);
```

Works perfectly fine. Hopefully this knowledge will help someone else.

UPDATE3: Scratch that. Dynamic cast doesn't convert Constant to a Value type. So if anyone knows how to do that, please let me know.

Comment: Are the kernels where this happens allocating more memory or doing a particular command?  Can you turn off optimization and see if it does it?  What OpenCL device?

Comment: Also, is it doing this on all the OpenCL devices or just one?

Comment: @Austin: It is neither happening on a particular command, or on memory allocation. The target is an AMD GPGPU I haven't tried it on any other target hardware since this is exclusively what I'm working on.

Comment: What about with kernel optimizations off?  The AMD platform can target  Intel CPUs, so it would be pretty easy to test it on another device.

Comment: is it giving a stack dump, what is the OS do you have llvm or clang installed in you device

Comment: @Chanakya.sun, The OS is Ubuntu 12.04, the LLVM version is 3.0

Comment: @Austin, the kernel code is tightly written for the GPGPU, running it on a different platform would not be an efficient use of time since it would require porting and in that case would not be the same code.

Comment: @Chanakya.sun, it hit an assert and failed, how is it giving me a stack dump?

Comment: Did you try building the program(s) with the optimization off?

Comment: @Austin: Sorry, yes, I did try that. No effect.

Answer (score 0):

I admit I don't understand the assertion error you get. However:

> The reason I use this command is that sometimes in a kernel there will be a store value that is a Constant. Since LLVM often requires a Value I needed a way of converting it. So I do a an allocation with an immediate store and load.

That doesn't make sense to me:

1. Any `llvm::Constant` *is* already an `llvm::Value`
2. Storing a value and then loading it back seems like an expensive nop...

Comment: It makes sense that it should work, I know. It inherits from User which inherits from Value. However, when I attempt to use it as a Value in say, a CreateStore(), it issues an error saying that the operand needs to be a Ptr to a Value type.

Comment: @user2765828 maybe edit the question to include a more complete code snippet that is generating the error.

Comment: I think at this point I'll create a new question specifically focused on the Constant to Value issue. This is the root of my troubles all other errors stem from this.