# LLVM converting a Constant to a Value

Tags: opencl, llvm, gpgpu, llvm-ir

I am using custom LLVM pass where if I encounter a store to 
where the compiler converts the value to a Constant; e.g. there is an explicit store:

```
X[gidx] = 10;
```

Then LLVM will generate this error:

```
aoc: ../../../Instructions.cpp:1056: void llvm::StoreInst::AssertOK(): Assertion `getOperand(0)->getType() == cast<PointerType>(getOperand(1)->getType())->getElementType() && "Ptr must be a pointer to Val type!"' failed.
```

The inheritance order goes as: Value<-User<-Constant, so this shouldn't be an issue, but it is. Using an a cast on the ConstantInt or ConstantFP has no effect on this error.
So I've tried this bloated solution:

```
Value *new_value;
if(isa<ConstantInt>(old_value) || isa<ConstantFP>(old_value)){
    Instruction *allocInst = builder.CreateAlloca(old_value->getType());
    builder.CreateStore(old_value, allocInst);
    new_value = builder.CreateLoad(allocResultInst);
}
```

However this solution creates its own register errors when different type are involved, so I'd like to avoid it.

Does anyone know how to convert a Constant to a Value? It must be a simple issue that I'm not seeing. I'm developing on Ubuntu 12.04, LLVM 3, AMD gpu, OpenCL kernels.

Thanks ahead of time.

EDIT:

The original code that produces the first error listed is simply:

```
builder.CreateStore(old_value, store_addr);
```

EDIT2:

This old_value is declared as
    Value *old_value = current_instruction->getOperand(0);

So I'm grabbing the value to be stored, in this case "10" from the first code line.

Comment: "The original code that produces the first error listed is simply" - could you provide a larger snippet, including how you create `old_value` and `new_value`?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the code that caused this first assertion, but its wording is pretty clear: you are trying to create a store where the value operand and the pointer operand do not agree on their types. It would be useful for the question if you'd provide the code that generated that error.

Your second, so-called "bloated" solution, is the *correct* way to store `old_value` into the stack and then load it again. You write:

> However this solution creates its own register errors when different type are involved

These "register errors" are the *real* issue you should be addressing.

In any case, the whole premise of "converting a constant to a value" is flawed - as you have correctly observed, all constants *are* values. There's no point storing a value into the stack with the sole purpose of loading it again, and indeed the standard LLVM pass "mem2reg" will completely remove such a sequence, replacing all uses of the load with the original value.

Comment: Edited. The register issue was the point of the original [post] (http://http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22647180/llvm-front-end-register-class-error-opencl-gpu-target). However given your last point, I don't understand why this issue exists in the first place.